# Error while passing the DataLoader to the training phase

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torchvision

I'm trying to train my CNN but I have this error in the Training Loop:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 3     training_loop(train_loader,epoch)
 

               in training_loop(loader, epoch)
   
      8         optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 9         outputs = classificador(inputs)
 

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Training loop is a function:

```
def training_loop(loader,epoch):
    running_loss = 0.
    running_accuracy = 0.
    
    for i, data in enumerate(loader):
        inputs,labels = data
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = classificador(inputs)
        `
```

I checked and "inputs" is a torch.tensor, so I don't know what is wrong with this

```
for epoch in range(5):
    print("Treinando")
    training_loop(train_loader,epoch)
    Fruitclass.eval()
    print("Validando...")
    training_loop(test_loader, epoch)
    FruitClass.train()
```

The classificador class is the one responsible for the model.

```
class classificador(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    #Parte convolucional
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,32,(3,3))
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,32,(3,3))
    self.activation = nn.ReLU()
    self.bnorm = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d((2,2))
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()        
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(54*54*32,128)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128,128)
    self.output = nn.Linear(128,10)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)                        

def forward(self,x):
    x = self.pool(self.bnorm(self.activation(self.conv1(x))))
    x = self.pool(self.bnorm(self.activation(self.conv2(x))))
    x = self.flatten(x)
    
    x = self.dropout(self.activation(self.linear1))
    x = self.dropout(self.activation(self.linear2))
    x = self.output(x)
    
    return x
```

I solved it. The classificador( ) should only be used to create the first model instance, after it i must use the model created to give the outputs

Comment: check `classificador` or post its code here.

Comment: done. I also deleted some parts that are not being used

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling `class` before creating `class object`. Fixing is easy:

```
# let Classificador with capital C be the class name 
class Classificador(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()    
# and so on - continue the rest of the class code

# then instantiate class object:
classificador = Classificador()

# now then you can call it in your code as you did:
outputs = classificador(inputs)
```

Read more examples to become more familiar with how to work with classes. Start from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Good luck!